# Can't find proper path for sanity.io default rich-date component

Tags: sanity

I want to use default sanity rich-date plugin in my custom input, but I can’t find the proper import path. I tried:

```
import DateInput from 'part:@sanity/form-builder/input/rich-date'
```

and it’s not working. Does anybody knows the right path?

Comment: Did you install the `@sanity/rich-date-input` using NPM? That import path should work.

Comment: Yes, i did, but this import isn't working. But everything is fine, i found right one.

Answer (score 0):

```
import DateInput from '../../node_modules/@sanity/date-input'
```